# Was the climax scene of Argo inspired by The Last King of Scotland?

Tags: reference, argo, the-last-king-of-scotland

In The Last King of Scotland (2006), Nicolas Gariggan escapes from Idi Amin in flight the same way Team from Argo (2012) escapes from the cops through flight.

So was the climax scene of Argo inspired by Last King of Scotland?

Comment: You might want to consider merging all your gazillions of different user accounts and just reusing one single account, rather than just creating a new one with each question. This way you will take full control of your content, including being able to edit your posts and accepting any possible answers to your questions. For more information, see the [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

Considering *Argo* is [based on a true story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argo_(2012_film)) from ~20 years before the [fictional story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_King_of_Scotland) *The Last King of Scotland* was written I very much doubt that *Argo*'s plot was seriously influenced by *The Last King of Scotland*. In case you wonder if the similarity is caused by Giles Foden copying the idea from *Argo* it looks like that is a dead end too considering Giles Foden published his book in 1998, and Tony Mendez [released his memoirs in 1999](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060957913) which I believe is the first public acknowledgement of the events that *Argo* is based on.

If you gave more information about why you think they are the same beyond leaving via airplane then I might be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: The ending scene of Argo was much more dramatic than what actually happened in real life... for example, IIRC there was no airport chase in real life; that was contrived by the filmmakers.

Comment: @ShizZ. I'm sure the writers added drama and action because that is what writers do in this situation. That being said escaping the country via airplane did happen in real life.